# How to Export Jasper 5.0.0 Server Reports

Tags: command-line-interface, export, accounts, report, server-settings

I'm in the process of spinning up a new Jasper server with the latest version of CentOS and Jasper running on it. I want to **export** the reports from my current server which is running **version 5.0.0**. I've looked around and a few sites mention you can do it through the **interface** which I've tried by going to **Manage -- Server Settings -- Export**.

I don't have this option though, there is no export option. My account has admin access. Does this need to be done with the **default jasper account** that is provisioned at initial setup? I also saw the export can be done through the **command line**.

I'd really like to get this export option setup rather than rebuild all of the reports. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Take a look http://community.jaspersoft.com/documentation/jasperreports-server-administration-guide/v550/import-and-export-through-command-line

Comment: So would I use js-export --uris /Reports/LMS --output-dir [folder-to-export-to] to export all of the reports under LMS? I guess I'm confused, is /Reports/LMS pointing to a location on the server I installed Jasper or the location in which my reports are stored through the jasper webpage of JasperStudio? Thanks!